# iOS 10 Upgrade Developer Checklist

Tags: ios, ios10

When upgrading your app from iOS 9 to iOS 10 SDK, which migrations are **necessary**, which are **recommended**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*The list is not yet exhaustive, you are invited to amend this community wiki answer. I will add more points during research too.*

---

## Necessary Changes

### App Transport Security

Apps will be enforced to use ATS from January 1st 2017 on, except for only a few exceptions. `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` should be deactivated for nearly all apps.

See 4:15 at [WWDC 2016 Session 706](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/706/)

### IPv6

You need to support IPv6. If you use DNS names and `NSUrlSession` or `NSUrlRequest`, you will be fine.

### XXXUsageDescription

`XXXUsageDescription` needs to be provided in `Info.plist` for even more system functionality needing authorization. In iOS 10 the app will exit when upon trying to access if those descriptions are missing.

## Recommended Changes

### UserNotifications Framework

There is a new framework for Local/Push Notifications. Also the visual style has changed. So if you reproduced the system notification style for showing in-app notifications, you should upgrade - the good news is that the new framework now supports showing notifications, even when the app is active.

### TouchedMoved

`touchesMoved` will be called much more often in iOS 10, so no performance critical code should be executed there. See 22:10 at [WWDC Session 220](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc16/220)

Comment: A very good list of general changes can be found here: http://alisoftware.github.io/conferences/2016/06/20/ios-10-api-diff/

Comment: `UIImageView` that loads `UIImage` and may require calling `layoutIfNeeded()` before accessing its size.